# What would be a good introductory reference for learning jet-bundle theory?

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, jets

I am interested in learning the theory of Jet bundles, and am aware of the standard reference "The geometry of jet bundles" by D. J. Saunders. However this appears to be a detailed book, suitable for those who wish to specialise in this area. Can somebody recommend a relatively more introductory book (for a reader who knows the necessary differential geometric pre-requisites for learning this subject, but has never encountered Jet bundles) ? Thanks so much !

Comment: The book "Exterior differential systems" has a section on Jet bundles, but maybe less than you're looking for. https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4613-9714-4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two articles by A.M. Vinogradov provide a gentle introduction:

"Local symmetries and conservation laws", Acta Applicandae Mathematica volume 2, pages 21–78(1984)

"An informal introduction to the geometry of jet spaces", available [here](https://diffiety.mccme.ru/djvu/informal.djvu).